# sequence concatadapter based on data type

Tags: android, kotlin, android-concatadapter

is it possible to use concatadapter based on data type.

normal implementation of concatadapter is

```
 val concatadapter = listOf(firstAdapter, secondAdapter, thirdAdapter)
```

while trying this code,

```
 for (nums in 0..15) {
      if (nums % 2 == 0) {
           concatAdapter.add(firstAdapter)
      } else {
           concatAdapter.add(secondAdapter)
      }
 }
```

the first "firstAdapter" and "secondAdapter" will be display.
But the next "firstAdapter" and "secondAdapter" is not displayed.

is there anything wrong on this code?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that other adapter is not visible is because you are adding same object for **"firstAdapter"** and **"secondAdapter"**  every time in concat adapter.

you have to initialise **"firstAdapter"** and **"secondAdapter"** when adding to concat adapter like below:

```
 concatAdapter=ConcatAdapter()
    for (nums in 0..15) {
        if (nums % 2 == 0) {
            concatAdapter.addAdapter(FirstAdapter(nums))
        } else {
            concatAdapter.addAdapter(SecondAdapter(nums))
        }
    }
    var layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
    binding.recycler.layoutManager = layoutManager
    binding.recycler.adapter=concatAdapter
```